# MenuItemCompat getActionView canno find symbol

Tags: java, android, menuitem, android-appcompat

I'm trying to implement in my app, search the view that only I am having this problem for quite some time:

```
(SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

I still say that it is the method I do not know what to do, the app is available from higher versions of Android 2.3.3 (API 10) up to version 5.0 (API 21). I assure you that in another app the same, same properties but different files works.

I am attaching the image (screen).

[image]
Thank you in advance

Comment: What type is your `searchItem`?

Comment: @PedroOliveira MenuItem

Comment: searchItem should be of type MenuItem

Comment: @MohammedAli SearchItem is an MenuItem